# Why do we vary the form of the attributes of HaShem in the selicho "Kail Rachum shmecho"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, selichot, nuschaot

In the selicho "Kail Rachum shmecho" we ask HaShem to do things because of ("lema'an") - a list of things. Some are in the masculine form eg shemecho and some in the feminine form eg amitoch, brisoch. Why?

Comment: I think not all nuschaot are the same on this matter. Can you clarify which you are using? Lita? Polin?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9663 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10890.