# לְךְ - what is this grammatical form?

Tags: tefilla, words, grammar-dikduk, prayer-book

Occasionally in a sefardi siddur, I see לְךְ. The first shva is a shva na, and the last is a shva nach. I always thought it was a typo but I keep seeing it now so I thought I'd ask a grammatical expert about it.
[image]
Is it a proper grammatical form/spelling and if so why is it used instead of לְךָ/לָךְ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "Lach" not "Lecha" in "Modim Anachnu Lach"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/why-lach-not-lecha-in-modim-anachnu-lach)

Comment: Thank you, those questions are about לָךְ, and I am talking about לְךְ

Comment: Nekudah tova, @Rabbi Kaii (pun intended)

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: @JoelK added a screenshot. I also remember seeing it recently in Machzor Avodat Hashem for Pesach. When I find it, I'll upload that too

Comment: Looks like a typo, as there's no such form. In your example, it should be repeating the words from a few lines up, which has the expected לָךְ.

Comment: Definitely a typo...

Comment: Had a feeling, thanks guys

Comment: How would that be pronounced? "Lich"?